# how to overwrite existing entities in doctrine?

Tags: php, doctrine

I am trying to run the command doctrine command for entities:

```
./vendor/bin/doctrine orm:convert-mapping  --from-database annotation ./Models
```

First time I run this command for generating entity mapping files then I modify the database table and again run the same command and got this error:

```
In ExportException.php line 36:

  Attempting to overwrite an existing file 'D:\xampp\htdocs\docx\Models\Address.php'.


orm:convert-mapping [--filter FILTER] [-f|--force] [--from-database] [--extend [EXTEND]] [--num-spaces [NUM-SPACES]] [--namespace [NAMESPACE]] [--] <to-type> <dest-path>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use switch -f or --force 
try this :

```
$ ./vendor/bin/doctrine orm:convert-mapping  --from-database --force annotation ./Models
```

and then regenerate entities